# Bypass Time.timeScale

Tags: unity-game-engine

I have a `Time.timeScale` that is equal to 0, making the whole game pause. Is there a way to make a game object not affected by the `Time.time` scale, so the empty game still functions while the whole game is still paused?

Comment: What code do you have so far?

Answer (score 1):

No, there is no way. [`FixedUpdate` functions will not be called when timeScale is set to zero](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Time-timeScale.html), so you cannot set the scale to zero and still have an object with `FixedUpdate` in motion because you would need `FixedUpdate` to update its transform.

You'll have to do something to pause the other objects without pausing the game, take a look at [this post](http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/565757/slow-motion-all-but-one-yet-another-round.html).

Comment: this is not an answer, its a comment to my answer.

Comment: I didn't even understand how your answer is helping him to achieve what he asked for. My answer tells him he cannot use timeScale and points to a link where someone achieved it.

Comment: If you didn't understand it that's fine, you can comment onto my answer and ill be glad to assist you there, but posting an answer of "No" directed at my answer does not answer the OP's question and isn't helping anybody. Apart from that you provide a link-only answer which is discouraged in stack overflow.

Comment: I'm sorry, "No" wasn't directed to your answer, it was an answer to his question "is there a way to make a game object not affected by time.timescale?" - _no!_, all objects are affected.

Comment: "No. FixedUpdate functions will not be called when timeScale is set to zero" is pretty direct to my answer, but i can assure you, `timeScale` doesn't necessarily have to affect a game object. Even though `FixedUpdate()` will not execute, `Update()` still will, as the renderer is still rendering frames, but the normal `deltaTime` will be `0f`.

Comment: Man, you voted me down and used that to fix your answer... anyway, I said that because he would have to do physics calculations inside FixedUpdate to move the object that is not being slowed down, but he can't do that because Fixed which he wouldn't be called. On the other hand, I still don't know how your answer helps him to move the object if timeScale is zero.

Comment: I voted you down because this is not an answer. I did say this is a comment to my answer which allowed me to improve it, but its just not an answer to OP's question. And my answer helps him to move his object because movements are driven by `deltaTime`, which in this case will `==0f` so i provide an alternative `delta` for him to base his movements off of.

Comment: Well, believe me or not it's not a comment to your answer, as I just explained. I'm a SO user for quite a long time, I know the difference between a comment and an answer.

Comment: He cannot use the alternative delta because physics calculations **have** to be made inside `FixedUpdate`!!!! That's the whole point of my "no" answer, to tell it's not possible because he needs `FixedUpdate` to control the not-slowed-down object!

Comment: no one ever said hes using physics calculations, also using my logic, you can create your own physics, its not hard.

Comment: @LOLslowSTi yes, you can create your own physics, but physics calculations _must_ be made inside `FixedUpdate`. And yes you are right about never using physics, I just assumed. I did it because new people in SO tend to post questions without enough details, so we comment or answer for them to detail their questions better, but also happens very frequently that the OP never goes back to the question, vote up/down or mark an answer, which maybe is the  case here so I feel we are both spending a huge amount of time. I swear my answer wasn't directed for you, sorry for the miscommunication.

Comment: Seeing this in the review queue, it definitely attempts to answer the question (without making any judgement on its merit), so I believe no explicit moderation action should be taken here.

Answer (score -1):

`Time.realtimeSinceStartup` is not affected by `Time.timeScale`

So basically you can create your own delta by doing

```
float lastRealTime = 0f;
float deltaRealTime = 0f;

public void Update()
{
    deltaRealTime = Time.realtimeSinceStartup - lastRealTime;
    lastRealTime = Time.realtimeSinceStartup;
}
```

http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Time-realtimeSinceStartup.html